# How to add paint effect for touching letters in wordsearch app in ANDROID

Tags: android, gridview, touch, paint, wordsearch

I have been doing a wordsearch app for 2+ months. I have developed it like all other simple wordsearch apps. But now i've changed things and want to develop it like magma mobile wordsearch app. For that i've coded a lot of logic to print characters in a GRID VIEW( I have taken a gridView for printing 10*10 grid). Now i'm struck at defining and developing paint effect like magma does with circle shape surrounding touched letters.

Now i'm confusing whether the paint like below will work on GridView or any TableRows or whatever...Please give me a thought.

![Magma mobile wordsearch touch effect][1]

Please suggest the way how to develop the same touch effect like they did. Screen shot is posted below.
Any ideas with programmatical concept is required.

Please check the image screenshot here
http://magmamobile.com/i/games/Words/promoimage750x380.jpg